# If/else in pandas ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string-comparison

I have the following code:

```
if data['Open'] >= data['Close']:
    data['Color'] = 'True'
```

What i want to do is compare the two add`Green` or `Red` in `[Color]` column in pandas. But i am getting

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can i fix this?

Comment: simply do  `data['Color'] = data['Open'] >= data['Close']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if it works:

```
import numpy as np
data['Color'] = np.where(data['Open'] >= data['Close'], 'True', 'whatever_value_you_want_if_the_condition_is_false')
```

Comment: There is no column 'color' yet i think that is why i am getting `KeyError: 'Color'`

Comment: If the condition is not true, what value you want to assign to data['Color']?